# Handling error 500 in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I am having some difficulty to handle the error 500 in my MVC4 application.
I've searched and found this post: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/619895/2394172)

And then I implemented this aproach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499406/2394172 (the long explained one)

The 404 error is ok, but I can't recover informations about the error on my other custom page when I get error 500.

I have the following code on my controller:

```
public ActionResult ServerError()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    ViewBag.Error = Server.GetLastError();
    return View();
}
```

The `Server.GetLastError()` always returns null, **how can I fix it** or **how can I recover it in other way**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using ELMAH. The tutorial which @Pure.Krome posted on that question was very helpfull to make the custom error pages, but to log the exceptions, ELMAH saved me.

Comment: This does NOT solve the Server.GetLastError() always returns null problem!

Comment: Ok it not solve the Server.GetLastError(), but since it was not my question, this answer is correct. Take a look at the bold question.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've actually looked at my code :blush: but [I'm guessing it might have something to do with this line of code](https://github.com/PureKrome/WorldDomination.Web.Mvc.ErrorHandling/blob/master/Code/WorldDomination.Web.Mvc/CustomErrorHandlingModule.cs#L120).

Basically, I have to clear the error so the normal ASP.NET pipeline code doesn't throw it again. *I think*.

Wether that's correct code or not .. I *think* that is why you're `GetLastError()` is always empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pure.Krome! I'll check this config and see what can I do.